# How to correctly handle custom keyboard when devices rotate in Beta 3

Tags: ios, keyboard, orientation, ios8, ios-app-extension

So I have been working on this Custom Keyboard for sometime, and everything was fine until iOS 8 Beta 3.

I have 5 xib created for iPhone Portrait, iPhone Landscape, iPad Portrair, iPad Landscape and iPhone 4 Portrait and here goes the issue.

In my KeyboardViewController:UIInputViewController, which was created when I created the custom keyboard based on the template.

I have this private method to determine which xib I should load, basically I was just checking the screen width and then I remove all subviews and add the new keyboard view.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"[DEBUG] viewWillLayoutSubviews");
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self determineKeyboardNib:self.view.frame.size];
}
//
//- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
//{
//    NSLog(@"[DEBUG] viewDidLayoutSubviews");
//    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
//    [self determineKeyboardNib:self.view.frame.size];
//}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    NSLog(@"[DEBUG] viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:");
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [self determineKeyboardNib:size];
}


/*
 * Determine which xib file to load based on the width of the screen
 */
- (void) determineKeyboardNib: (CGSize)size
{
    NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter if");
    KeyboardIBBackend *keyboard_view;
    // determine device
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter iPad");
        // iPad
        if (size.width > 1000) {
            NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter iPad Landscape");
            // landscape
            keyboard_view = [KeyboardIBBackend keyboardiPadLandscapeView];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter iPad Portrait");
            // portrait
            keyboard_view = [KeyboardIBBackend keyboardiPadPortraitView];
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter iPhone");
        // iPhone
        if (size.width > 500){
            NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter iPhone Landscape");
            // landscape
            keyboard_view = [KeyboardIBBackend keyboardiPhone5LandscapeView];
        }else if(size.width > 450){
            NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter iPhone 4 Portrait");
            // portrait
            keyboard_view = [KeyboardIBBackend keyboardiPhone4LandscapeView];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Enter iPhone 5 Portrait");
            keyboard_view = [KeyboardIBBackend keyboardiPhonePortraitView];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: Exit if");
    keyboard_view.parentview = self;
    // remove previous keyboard view
    for (UIView *v in [self.view subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    // add the newly determined view
    NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: before addSubview");
    [self.view addSubview:keyboard_view];
    NSLog(@"[DEBUG] determineKeyboardNib: after addSubview");
}
```

First of all, I tried to put this method in - (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator but is not getting called no matter Beta 2 or Beta 3.

As a result, I put that method in viewWillLayoutSubviews:, and it worked like a charm prior to Beta 3.

In Beta 3, when I rotate the device, viewWillLayoutSubviews, is getting called indefinitely. I suppose that was because in detemineKeyboardNib method, the last line is to

```
[self.view addSubview:keyboard_view]
```

which might have caused it to call viewWillLayoutSubviews again and again. However, this was not the case in Beta 2.

Then I tried to pur determineKeyboardNib inside viewDidLayoutSubviews, the same as above.

So I am wondering what is the correct way to handle device rotation in Beta 3. I believe viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: should be the correct way to go but it is really not getting called when I rotate the device...Please help here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you fixed already, but a solution that I found that seems to work is to put the code in an if block that only runs if the size has changed, and call super viewWillLayoutSubviews after.

so like this:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
  if(self.size.frame.width != self.someClassVariableToTrackWidth)
   {
       self.someClassVariableToTrackWidth = self.size.frame.width;
       //call stuff here
   }

[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}
```

I'm looking for a better solution since this was always a hackish method and when I find it i'll post it.